# Match any dot that doesn't have a certain word before

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with a pattern similar to the following one:

```
TITLE.wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA. BBBB: bbbb.
```

I want to split this strings by ". " for getting something like: `['TITLE','wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA', 'BBBB: bbbb']`

The problem is that the string '`wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA'` contains a dot itself, so by spliting the string as I previously said, the real output would be:`['TITLE','wordX','aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA', 'BBBB: bbbb']`

Therefore, I want a regex that allows me to tell the split to find "every dot which is not followed by wordX". Looking for this on the internet, I found that some suggested using the negative lookahead for these cases, like `^((?!wordX).)*$`. Nevertheless, this has not worked for me apparently (maybe I am not using it the right way).

Due to all this, I would like to know how to build a regex for matching every dot that does not have the wordX inmediately before and that is followed by a space.

Comment: The first and second part of your question do not seem to correspond. Do you want to find a dot only when it is followed by a phrase, or only if it is not followed by a certain phrase? If it's the former, a simple positive lookahead should suffice, e.g. \.(?=wordX).

Comment: If you were to split the string on the matching dots would you not get `["TITLE.wordX", " aaa", ": AAAAAAA;AAAAA", " BBBB: bbbb"]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland maybe it is not clear in the question, but I am splitting by "dot+space"

Comment: @oriberu I want to do the second thing, find the dots that don't have the wordX inmediately before

Comment: Your last comment directly contradicts the last sentence of your question and that sentence says nothing about the need for the dot to be followed by a space. Please edit.

Comment: I am sorry, I have just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not completely clear which scenario you want exactly, so here are a couple of options with what is matched in each case.

Positive lookahead:

```
\.(?=wordX)

TITLE.wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA. BBBB: bbbb.
     ^
```

Negative lookahead:

```
\.(?!wordX)

TITLE.wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA. BBBB: bbbb.
           ^    ^               ^           ^
```

Positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=wordX)\.

TITLE.wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA. BBBB: bbbb.
           ^
```

Negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!wordX)\.

TITLE.wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA. BBBB: bbbb.
     ^          ^               ^           ^
```

You should in any case reword your question. Cheers.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I did reword my question. The alternative I want is the last one you talk about, but, when trying it at https://www.regextester.com/ it seems to also mark the dot after wordX

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I have tried it at another website and it does work (ithe problem was the first page I talked about was for javascript). Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript and lookbehinds have quite the non-history. But it's in the 2018 standard and we can hope for widespread implementation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
^(.*?)\.((.*?)(?<!wordX)\.(.*?))\. (.*)\.
```

Given:

```
TITLE.wordX. aaa.: AAAAAAA;AAAAA. BBBB: bbbb.
```

With groups:

```
\1 \2 \5
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hPY8JX/2

Oops, update for JS?

```
^(.*?)\.(wordX\..*)\. (.*)\.
```

https://regex101.com/r/V49Fiw/1